# How to discard unsaved changes to a view when editing it leads to a WSOD?

Tags: views, 8

This is one of those times when I tried to add something and realized that I've got it applied to all displays. This time it was a vocabulary filter, so I clicked cancel and it didn't register so I clicked back to site.

After that I tried to edit and it returned

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

The log shows this:

> Exception: No entity type for field vid on view VIEW in
>   Drupal\views\Plugin\views\HandlerBase->getEntityType() (line 712 of
>   /PATH/core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/HandlerBase.php).

I checked the active config and couldn't find anything with a vid. Clearing cache and reimporting the view config didn't fix it. So, is there a way?

Comment: See this [Drupal Core issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2664304)

Comment: How about deleting the view before reimporting.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A quick fix would be to delete the data from the expirable key/value store:

```
\Drupal::keyValueExpirable('tempstore.shared.views')
  ->delete('view_id');
```

Alternatively you could wait a week until it expires itself - probably not practical :)

Comment: Could you add a little context to your answer? I’ve faced this issue in the past but am not sure how to apply the above... thanks!

Comment: @Prestosaurus: Use a custom module, or - even easier and with less hassle - the Drush PHP CLI. https://drushcommands.com/drush-9x/php/php:cli/

Comment: There’s also the /devel/php page if you have the devel module installed @Prestosaurus. Failing that you could literally delete the row from the key_value_expire table and clear the cache

Comment: Just run this command with drush:

`drush eval "\Drupal::keyValueExpirable('tempstore.shared.views')->delete('YOUR_VIEW_ID');"`

Comment: You can also enter the PHP shell with `drush [@example.com] php`, and run it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Clive answer here, you can delete that particular row in the table 'key_value_expire'. Here is the sample:

- viewName: homepage_slider
- Then first check if that view exists in the table anywhere using the SQL command:
- select * from key_value_expire where name='homepage_quote_slider';
- if it shows the data then run the below command:
- delete from key_value_expire where name='homepage_quote_slider';
- Go back to your view and refresh it couple of times if it's still showing an error.