# How to revert a view that has pending changes in temporary storage?

Tags: views, 8

I had a working view.
I have tried to modify it by removing the the relationships then it crashes.
Now I am not able to edit the view.

How to revert back the previous changes of view.

Here is the error appearing in edit page of view

```
Notice: Undefined index: field_product_overview in Drupal\views\Plugin\views\HandlerBase->getEntityType() (line 700 of core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/HandlerBase.php).
Drupal\views\Plugin\views\HandlerBase->getEntityType() (Line: 250)
Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\EntityField->access(Object) (Line: 1047)
Drupal\views\ViewExecutable->_initHandler('field', Array) (Line: 898)
Drupal\views\ViewExecutable->initHandlers() (Line: 1230)
```

Comment: When you didn't have saved the View you can revert it by deleting the Views tempstore, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/276026/how-to-discard-unsaved-changes-to-a-view-when-editing-it-leads-to-a-wsod

Comment: thanks you are right. I just deleted the view_id from key_value_expire table and now it's working. Thanks